# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in block of code made in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I don't understand whats causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS - KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS error in my app.

When my app starts up, my AppDelegate.m I make a call to a SKProductRequest to get all the available IAPs for an app. It works sometime but not others and I'm at a loss to figure out why. My code in the AppDelegate to do this looks like the following:

```
[[MyIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
            if (success) {
                for (SKProduct *prod in products) {
                    // set up pricing in the db
                    [Price setPriceOfProduct:prod.productIdentifier WithLocale:prod.priceLocale AndAmount:prod.price];
                }
            }
        }];
```

The requestProducts... method is simply:

```
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];
}
```

Any help on this is much appreciated - if I've left out any key information then just let me know.

Comment: If you show a symbolicated stack trace it might help.  Also, anything that's printed in the debug console when it happens.

Comment: @PhillipMills just waiting on Finder to re-index so I can symbolicate the logs (hoping this is the reason it can't symbolicate at the moment!).

Comment: Did you have the symbolicated stack trace yet? All I can see here is a concurrency problem that can cause you `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Are you sure you called `requestProductsWithCompletionHandler` only once? And, can you show the code of `[Price setPriceOfProduct:WithLocale:AndAmount:]`?

Answer (score 0):

For dealing with BAD_ACCESS, you should have a look at my answer in this post :
[iOS error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException Range or index out of bounds'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295175/ios-error-terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsrangeexception-range-or-i/24296115#24296115)

See how to add the "malloc_error_break" breakpoint. This might help to find out which line is causing the bug.

In your case, I suspect that your MyIAPHelper instance, or _productsRequest has been deallocated.
To check this, you should override the "dealloc" method of MyIAPHelper like this :

```
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"MyIAPHelper is deallocated");
}
```

And add a breakpoint on the NSLog to see if dealloc is called.

You should also check that your _productsRequest property is retained (i.e. declared like this : @property(nonatomic,retain) SKProductsRequest* productsRequest;

Answer (score -1):

Try `Block_copy()` instead of `copy` on the handler.

```
_completionHandler = Block_copy(completionHandler);
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832458/using-blocks-causes-exc-bad-access?rq=1) should help.

(and don't forget to call `Block_release(...)` when you're done with it.

Comment: Isn't `copy` the same as `Block_copy()`

Comment: @3329 it seems as though using Block_copy copies it to the heap rather than the stack.

Comment: @Stephen Furlani can you tell me when the block should be released please? At the end of the requestProducts.... method?

Comment: @Ger Yes, it does and also `copy` too. I've checked it and found that `copy` did actually call to `_Block_copy()` which was also called by `Block_copy()`.