# iOS error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException Range or index out of bounds'

Tags: ios

I recently picked up doing iOS development.

I am new to the whole thing, so please forgive my ignorance.

I ran into an issue in my app where when i start a stream (like streaming live audio), the app crashes (ipod touch 5th gen running iOS 7.1).

I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'.
```

Can someone help me in diagnosing this issue and possible solutions?

Thanks!!

ironmantis7x

EDIT: Here is the full error message:

```
2014-06-18 13:18:39.181 miraathradios[845:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x2f6f0fd3 0x39e3bccf 0x2f6f0f15 0x2f6364f7 0x63c65 0x63b35 0x60a8b 0x300d9c73 0x2f6bc25b 0x2f6bb72b 0x2f6b9f1f 0x2f624f0f 0x2f624cf3 0x34546663 0x31f7016d 0x588a9 0x587f8)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(lldb)
```

partial code:

```
- (JHTickerDirection)detecteDirection:(NSString *) title{
    //NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    NSCharacterSet *letters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
    unichar ch = [title characterAtIndex:6];
    if ([letters characterIsMember:ch]) {
        return JHTickerDirectionLTR;
    }else{
        return JHTickerDirectionRTL;
    }

}
```

Comment: No one can help if you don't post the relevant code and point out the issue.

Comment: Looks like you call `characterAtIndex` with an wrong value. More i can`t say without code.

Comment: @maddy -- i am new to ios development and trying to figure out what i don't know. please provide constructive feed back with help. manners are important as well as the knowledge that goes along with it.

Comment: @jens: how to i trace back to which file characterAtIndex goes to? debugging in iOs seems different than Android.

Comment: You shold read the xcode documentation for Debugging.

Comment: Thanks @Jens! will do! And your manners are excellent!

Comment: Is that the only console output for the error? 

In XCode you can click to set a break point in the left margin next to the code. Try that at what you think is the offending spot & see if you can get more specifics.

From what you posted, it seems like you're perhaps dealing with a string (a title or label?) that is blank or too short what you're asking it to do, so it throws an exception when it can't find a character at the specified position (index). 

A more complete example would help narrow things down. 
And have a nice day :)

Comment: @mc01: yes, it is a title that it is complaining about in the code. Let me post the code ... give me a sec.

Comment: Code is too long to post (reached character limit). Any ideas on how I can post the code??

Comment: Where's it getting the data for the title? Maybe just post that chunk where you're trying to set it (or whatever you're doing w/the string)

Comment: @mc01: yes ... let me do that ... stand by ...

Comment: snippet of code posted

Comment: So you're hard-coding the index at character 6 - if the argument "title" passed in is anything shorter (say only 4 characters), or perhaps it's a unicode character split in 2 (like ä split into a and ¨), "ch" could be undefined and "out of range." Perhaps consider looping through "title" by character & seeing if it's within a given range of unicode characters, rather than hard-coding the index & checking against the entire alphabet string.

Comment: @mc01 -- you were right!!  I changed part of the code from a 6 to 0 for a quick fix. The app now works (mostly). I have a sunchrounus thread issue still where I get a time out error, but that is a separate issue (???). LOL!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're hard-coding the index to look for characterAtIndex: 6.
If the argument "title" passed in is anything shorter (say only 4 characters), or perhaps it's a unicode character split in 2 (like ä split into a and ¨), "ch" could be undefined and "out of range." Perhaps consider looping through "title" by character & seeing if it's within a given range of unicode characters, rather than hard-coding the index & checking against the entire alphabet string.

Comment: issue fixed!! for everyone that provided constructive and meaningful assistance with guides and suggestions, thanks!! you helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

When debugging, I strongly advise you to add 2 special breakpoints :
One for all exceptions.
And one for all "BAD_ACCESS" errors.

When those 2 breakpoints are enabled, xcode will automatically break on the faulting line instead of directly crashing without giving more informations.

To activate them, follow these steps :

- open the breakpoint left tab, and click the "+" button in the bottom left corner.
- select Add Exception Breakpoint.
- Right click on the new breakpoint, and configure it this way :

  - Exception : All
  - Break : On throw
  - Action :  Add Action
  - Options : leave the box unchecked.
- Then add a symbolic break point ("+" button -> Add Symbolic Breakpoint)
- Configure the breakpoint this way :

  - Symbol : malloc_error_break
  - don't modify all the other options

You're done for starting debugging !

Comment: ALL: I will read the docs on debugging and come back with questions. As I said before, I am new to iOS development so I have a lot of stupid newbie questions ... please excuse my novice nature...

Comment: ALL: i do want to say thanks to everyone who helped with constructive and helpful comments and suggestions.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful!  +1 for finding awesome tips while looking for information about other issues :)